# Prompting users with a message once they connect to my wifi-router

Tags: networking, wifi, router

How is it possible to program or configure our wifi routers so that when there was a new connection the user would be prompted with a message?

Comment: Google how to implement a capture portal, then the user will get a message in its browser.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give you a start.
The feature is called [Captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). Its not available on all the routers.

For configuring this on a Linksys router, follow these [steps](http://dev.wifidog.org/wiki/doc/install/openwrt).
And refer this [page](http://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/wifi-setup-router-based-terms-of-use-page-505173/) for more information.